# how do i restrict access to file URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

i have a few files on a webserver that i want to restrict the access to.
eg  www.example.com/privatefiles/secret.txt

i have tried this:

routes.rb:

```
get '/privatefiles/:file.:ext' => 'file_handler#authenticate'
#.......
```

file_handler_controller.rb:

```
class FileHandlerController < ApplicationController
     def authenticate
         if(session[:user_id] == ADMIN)
             sendfile
         else
             redirect_to '/NO'
         end
     end
end
```

i find this behaves correctly when i put in the URL of a file that **doesn't** exist but when a file exists the route gets ignored and the browser will just go straight to the file, and never even reaches the controller

Comment: In order to restrict access to files, I usually rather put them outside my web root and access it through a specific handler in which you can also do other kinds of checks than just basic user authentication (ex : log downloads, limit number of access, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

in routes:

```
get '/privatefiles/:file.:ext' => 'file_handler#fetch_file'
```

in your controller:

```
class FileHandlerController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate

  def fetch_file
    # send/ show file code here
    sendfile
  end

  private

  def authenticate
    unless (session[:user_id] == ADMIN)
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => 'Doing something nasty, huh?'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: still bypasses the controller. Possible bug in rails?

Comment: No, issue is here: `(session[:user_id] == ADMIN)` how are you validating this condition?